# Match a string pattern in line and replace line with pattern in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to search for a string pattern in a line and if found replace the whole line with the matched string pattern.

My string pattern starts with 2 alpha characters and followed with either 5 or 6 numeric characters. Ex. **HR12345** or **HR123456**

Here is sample of how the lines with the pattern looks like.

```
Class cum accumsan. In. Pellentesque nec magna interdum fusce metus, massa aliquam HR032145 
Amet commodo arcu, felis orci Per. Facilisis blandit rhoncus hac porttitor ut duis eu HR32145 
Mattis quis magna, suspendisse HR32146 aucibus vel, fames Nonummy molestie penatibus ad. 
Nascetur mattis ad egestas et nec HR032111 Penatibus posuere. Posuere.
Inceptos consectetuer neque nullam HR032114. rutrum Eleifend. 
Netus tortor conubia parturient sapien interdum adipiscing sociis luctus integer HR032113 
HR032112 Mattis erat a ante. Rutrum. Mattis risus fames. Euismod sapien morbi habitasse. 
Platea sapien vitae Risus. Erat dictum elit dapibus convallis. 
Facilisis ut dis morbi integer fusce dolor Et class Primis iaculis. 
Aptent per risus phasellus HR032188
```

After search replace it should look like

```
HR032145 
HR32145 
HR32146 
HR032111
HR032114 
HR032113 
HR032112 
Platea sapien vitae Risus. Erat dictum elit dapibus convallis. 
Facilisis ut dis morbi integer fusce dolor Et class Primis iaculis. 
HR032188
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following simple find and replace:

**Find:**

```
^.*(HR\d+).*$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1
```

This replacement will only happen with lines containing `HR` followed by one or more digits.  Hence, the lines which do not have this pattern will not even match, and no replacement will take place there.